# Can a task be sent to an Outlook Email box and then worked by anyone with access to that box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a special email box/address set up for escalated messages (e.g. X1_Announcments@company.com) in addition to our normal individual email address. And there are two people who work the emails which hit that box. Instead of sending a task to them both simultaneuosly it would be nice if it is possible to send a task to the specialty email box for either of them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is easy: Create a group for them, then assign the task to the group with the "Assign a single task to each group entered (Do not expand groups)" box checked.